# Nhibernate adding new entry for child object on update

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
 public CaseMap()
        {
            Id(c => c.ID);//.GeneratedBy.Increment();

            Map(c => c.CIN);
            Map(c => c.CaseNumber);
            Map(c => c.Name);
            Map(c => c.RegistryNumber);

            References(c => c.ApplicantType).Column("FK_ApplicantTypeId").Cascade.None();
            References(c => c.ApplicationType).Column("FK_ApplicationTypeId").Cascade.None();
            References(c => c.AVSUser).Column("FK_UserId").Cascade.None();
            References(x => x.Program).Column("FK_ProgramId").Cascade.None(); 

            References(c => c.CaseApplicant).Column("FK_CaseApplicantId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
            References(c => c.Address).Column("FK_AddressId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
            References(x => x.Spouse).Column("FK_SpouseId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();


            Map(c => c.SpouseLink);
            Map(c => c.Status);
            Map(c => c.CreatedDate);
            Map(c => c.UpdatedDate);
            Map(c => c.IsArchived);



            Table("tbl_Case");
        }
```

Update method -

```
 public bool Update(T persistableEntity)
        {
            if (persistableEntity != null)
            {
                session.BeginTransaction();
                session.Update(persistableEntity);
                session.Transaction.Commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The Update Call updates the Case table but adding new entry for child objects  like CaseApplicant,Address and Spouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was code error

Instead of

```
 cCase.Address = new CaseAddress();
         cCase.Address.Street = record.ResidenceStreet;
```

It should have been just

```
cCase.Address.Street = record.ResidenceStreet;
```

cCase.Address = new CaseAddress() was creating a new object for CaseAddress result in new entry.

Also the update method should be session.Merge instead of update

```
public bool Update(T persistableEntity)
        {
            if (persistableEntity != null)
            {
                session.BeginTransaction();
                session.Merge(persistableEntity);
                session.Transaction.Commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```